# date loop increment and growing variable ( mootools )

Tags: javascript, mootools

Can someone please take a look at this with fresh eyes.

```
var start_date = Date.parse('2013-07-01');
var i_date = Date.parse('2013-07-5');

console.log(start_date + '---before loop ');

for (var n = start_date; n < i_date; n.increment()) {
    console.log(start_date + '---inside loop ');
}
console.log(start_date + '---after loop ');
```

This code produces this:

```
Mon Jul 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)---before loop
Mon Jul 01 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)---inside loop
Tue Jul 02 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)---inside loop
Wed Jul 03 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)---inside loop
Thu Jul 04 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)---inside loop
Fri Jul 05 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time)---after loop
```

**Why** does start_date variable grow?

(fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/3bqR3/) if needed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `n` and `start_date` are pointing to the same object. You need to clone the date by creating new `Date` object, for example:

```
n = new Date(start_date);
```

[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3bqR3/1/).

Example:

```
> a = new Date()
Sun Jul 07 2013 19:51:09 GMT+0600 (Ekaterinburg Standard Time)
> b = a
Sun Jul 07 2013 19:51:09 GMT+0600 (Ekaterinburg Standard Time)
> c = new Date(a)
Sun Jul 07 2013 19:51:09 GMT+0600 (Ekaterinburg Standard Time)
// Do some stuff with "a"
> a
Sat Jun 29 2013 19:51:09 GMT+0600 (Ekaterinburg Standard Time)
> b
Sat Jun 29 2013 19:51:09 GMT+0600 (Ekaterinburg Standard Time)
> c
Sun Jul 07 2013 19:51:09 GMT+0600 (Ekaterinburg Standard Time)
```

Comment: @Rikard I got like 3 downvotes in a row on totally different questions, so it probably has nothing to do with the answer quality

Comment: @mishik, thanks for your answer! On the post you suggest `start_date = new Date(n);` but on your fiddle you have the inverted `var n = new Date(start_date);`. The fiddle puts me on the right track, your explanation confuses me :). Was it a typo mistake?